# How to search for a specific value in a .csv file using groovy

Tags: csv, groovy

I have a .csv file for Unloco code and I want to search if a specific port code exists in the .csv file.

File:

```
ADALV,Andorra la Vella,,,4230N 00131E
ADCAN,Canillo,,,4234N 00135E
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate all lines in your file with this kind of code:

```
def f = new File(myfile)
f.withReader("UTF-8"){ r->
    r.splitEachLine( ',' ){ line->
        if(line[0]=='ADCAN'){ 
            println "found: $line"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know that the code exists in the file and don't care where you could do the following, the `text` method will read the entire file into a string however so not great if dealing with large files.

```
new File( 'myfile.csv' ).text.contains( 'ADCAN' )
```